# How to check existing Android Exchange Domain settings?

Tags: exchange, outlook, device-migration, samsung-smart-switch

I am installing my wife's new phone using Samsung Smart Switch.

It nicely installs all apps, including Outlook, however it does not copy the **account settings** for her Exchange mail.

I know her Outlook mail address, mail server name and password, but have not been able to find her *domain setting* in any documentation or in the settings of her old phone (domain\username).

Is there any way to discover that domain setting on her **old** mobile? I have tried to find it, without any luck. And service desk of her work is unavailable during the weekend. Hence my question.

Comment: Are you aware that by using MS Outlook app the credentials are saved in the Microsoft cloud which acts as a man-in-the middle between Outlook app and the actual mail server. Hence it is not a mail app, instead it is a mail viewer for a mail system that is located in the MS cloud. As we are talking about a work profile this may be disallowed by the company (give foreign companies access to the work mail system).

Comment: Hi Robert, tnx for your feedback.. it is allowed by the Company... and we discovered the domain credentials in the meantime ... It's working now..Cheers, Albert

Comment: Do you use office365 or a company exchange install? In both cases, she can likely find the domain in her desktop outlook settings (probably she uses a desktop machine in work).